# el.addEventListener() on select in other Vue instance

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a custom select component which sits inside an anonymous Vue instance.
It has a visual part which reflects the `<select>` options, and clicking on the visual part updates the `<select>`. The `<select>` itself would be hidden.

In another Vue instance I am looking for certain form inputs to calculate a form complete status.
I am doing so by getting the inputs from the dom (`document.querySelector('#someInput')`) and adding eventListeners.

The problem is, that the event on the custom select is not triggering (bubbling?) because it's inside another instance.

Here is a simplified sample. The visual part is not reflecting select changes to keep the code lean.

```html
<div id="appControl">
</div>

<div class="vue-instance">
  <form-select inline-template>
    <div>
      <select name="color" id="sampleSelect" @change="handleSelectChange" ref="htmlSelect">
        <option value="">--select--</option>
        <option value="blue">Blue</option>
        <option value="green">Green</option>
        <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
      </select>
      
      <p>Change select</p>
      <div class="buttons-wrapper">
        <button @click="setSelect('blue')">Blue</button>
        <button @click="setSelect('green')">Green</button>
        <button @click="setSelect('yellow')">Yellow</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form-select>
</div>
```

```js
Vue.component('form-select', {
  
  methods: {
    handleSelectChange: function(e){
        console.log('Component handleSelectChange', e.target.value);
      
      // ...here could be code to update the visual part
    },
    
    setSelect: function(val) {
      // set selected on <select>
      this.$refs.htmlSelect.value = val;
      
      // Trigger change event on <select>
      this.$refs.htmlSelect.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
    },
    
  }
});


// Other Vue instance
var appControl = new Vue({
  el: "#appControl",
  
  mounted: function(){
    // Get <select> from DOM and listen to change event
    var selectField = document.querySelector("#sampleSelect");
    
    // Listen to 'change'. This is not firing
    selectField.addEventListener('change', this.handleDomSelectChange);
  },
  
  methods: {
    handleDomSelectChange: function(e){
        console.log('appControl handle select change', e.target.value);
    }
  }
})


// Generic Vue Instances
var vueInstances = document.querySelectorAll('.vue-instance');

vueInstances.forEach(function(vueInstance) {
    new Vue({
    el: vueInstance
  })
})
```

I know that I can emit a custom event like so:

```
handleSelectChange: function(e){
        console.log('Component handleSelectChange', e.target.value);
      
      // Emit custom event
      appControl.$emit('select-change', e.target);
    },
```

and in the `appControl` instance

```js
mounted: function(){
    // Get <select> from DOM and listen to change event
    var selectField = document.querySelector("#sampleSelect");
    
    // Listen to 'change'. This is not firing
    selectField.addEventListener('change', this.handleDomSelectChange);
    
    // Listen to custom event
    this.$root.$on('select-change', function(el) {
      console.log('*** select-change in appControl:', el.value, el.id);
    });
  },
```

but I don't want some "global" event and then figure out where it came from, just the normal
`iKNowTheElement.addEventListener(...)`

**Edit** Expected result for code sample without custom event:

When selecting "green" on `<select>` or `<button>`
Console outputs
`"Component handleSelectChange", "green"`
and `"appControl handle select change" green`

Answer (score 0):

1. Can you clarify, why do you need several instances of Vue?
2. I copy pasted your code into codesandbox and select works fine(changes on button clicks and on select menu clicks)
3. Probably two-way data binding with `v-model` can provide more convenient solution https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html

#### Update

Sadly there are no other way to communicate between separate vue instances other than emiting some event on instance directly, but this way of communication between components seem clumsy.

Try to nest `form-control`s in a single vue-controlled div and emit events from children by `this.$emit('<event-name>', payload)`, and then catch them in parent component by placing event listener like `@<event-name>="handlerFunction"`(payload will be avalible as first argument in handler)

P.S. If you are aiming at something more than vue-controlled todolist, consider using vue-cli or some bundling tool of your choice, like webpack or rollup

CodeSandbox example: https://codesandbox.io/s/eladdeventlistener-on-select-in-other-vue-instance-ox4qt

Comment: Please check again - you probably didn't see the console log "appControl handle select change [color]". Sorry for not clarifying the expected result. I have edited my question.
Vue was originally just used for smaller component functionalities. We are gradually moving over to use Vue on a larger scale, with a single Vue instance and single file components, but for now many components will stay inside their own instances.
Can you explain how two-way binding could solve this?

Comment: Updated answer after your comment